# Can VANS RV-12 with Rotax 912 ULS be used/equiped in IFR?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, aircraft-certification, rotax-912

May an instrument rated pilot fly a VANS RV-12 with a Rotax 912 ULS with the following equipment in VMC, under instrument flight rules for IFR training?

> Dynon 10" HDX Touch Screen Primary Display
> Dynon Autopilot Control Panel SV-AP-Panel
> Dynon Knob Control Panel SV-Knob-Panel
> Dynon ADSB In/Out
> Dynon Remote Mount Transponder
> Garmin GTR200 Comm Radio

Also, is it possible to re-certify it for IFR use? If yes, what additional equipment is required?

Comment: According to which regulations? FAA, UK CAA, EASA, some other country?

Comment: Is that the only equipment it has??